# show hashed password as plain password in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I saved has password as follows:

```
   function hashPassword() {
     if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha256'));
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
    }

    function setIP() {
          /* IP address insert */
        $exec = exec("hostname"); //the "hostname" is a valid command in both windows and linux
        $hostname = trim($exec); //remove any spaces before and after
        $ip = gethostbyname($hostname); //resolves the hostname using local hosts resolver or DNS
        $this->data['User']['ip'] = $ip;
    }

    function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->hashPassword();
        $this->setIP();
        return true;
    }
```

Now how could I show this password as plain text. i.e: the following code retrieves all info of user table:

```
function manage_user() {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $users = $this->User->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
```

But the password is hash format how can I get it as plain text? 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no situation where you should be showing passwords as plain text...

Comment: You can't - that's the whole point of hashing. Once its stored in the db as a hash you can't reverse it into plain text

Comment: Say, I want to show password of all users when super admin will log in to manage users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of hashing is that you cannot reverse engineer the password. So that when your database is hacked or leaked no harm can be done with the passwords.

Any website showing you your own password has a severe security problem and I would not use it.

So the answer is: No you can't and you shouldn't